# Jquery mobile open pdf online and can't go back to where it come from

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use JQuery mobile in my index.html page

I have `data-role="page" id="loginPage"` and `data-role="page" id="main"`

which is start from **"loginPage"** and then **"main"** after successful login.

the problem is in the "main" page there are buttons that create dialog box

and in each dialog box has link to open PDF online content when it's open

PDF Content in the browser if I want to navigate back to **"main"** page not **"login"** page

what should I do ???

Please advice, Thank In advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.mobile.changePage` method like

```
$.mobile.changePage( "#main", {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});
```